# Mysql Workbench - The best way to organize running frequently used SQL queries while development

Tags: mysql, sql, intellij-idea, autocomplete, mysql-workbench

I'm a java dev who uses Mysql Workbench as a database client and IntelliJ IDEA as an IDE. Every day I do SQL queries to the database from 5 up to 50 times a day.

Is there a convenient way to save and re-run frequently used queries in Mysql Workbench/IntelliJ IDEA so that I can:

1. avoid typing a full query which has already been used again
2. smoothly access a list of queries I've already used (e.g by auto-completion)

If there is no way to do it using Mysql Workbench / IDEA, could you please advise any good tools providing this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Workbench should remember your tabs, so you can just keep a couple around for those purpose; also, I save them as sql files, since Workbench can start misremembering things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Stored Procedures, one per query (or sequence of queries).  Give them short names (to avoid needing auto-completion).

For example, to find out how many rows in table `foo` (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo;`).

One-time setup:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE foo_ct
BEGIN;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
CALL foo_ct();
```

You can pass arguments in in order to make minor variations.  Passing in a table name is somewhat complex, but numbers of dates, etc, are practical and probably easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed SQLyog for your mysql then you can use **Favorites** menu option in which you can save your query and in one click it will automatically writes the saved query on Query Editor.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct - depending on the version of the Query Browser they are either called Favorites or Snippets - the problem being you can't create sub-folders to group them. And keeping tabs open is an option  - but sometimes the browser 'dies' - and you're back to ground 0. So the obvious solution I came up with - create a database table! I have a few 'metadata' fields for descriptions - the project a query is associated to; problem the query solves; and the actual query.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep your query library in an SQL file and load that when WB opens (it's automatically opened when you restart WB and that file was open on last close). When you want to run a specific query place the caret in it's text and press Ctrl+Enter (Cmd+Enter on Mac) to run only this query. The organization of that SQL file is totally up to you. You have more freedom than any "favorites" solution can give you. You can even have more than one file with grouped statements.

Additionally, MySQL Workbench has a query history (see the Output Tab), which is saved to disk, so you can return to a query even month's after you wrote it.